# Why can't I view the public folder of Zend Framework Project?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I recently started learning zend framework. I am trying to access the index.php inside the public folder, but when i test the project using **WAMP server in browser**, I can't find the public folder in the web root. I can see other folders like applications, library, docs but there isn't any public folder.

Why can't I view the `public` folder of Zend Framework Project?

**UPDATE** my .htacess file inside the /public folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't access'. Give us more detail on what your are trying to do.
Is it the web server, is it you who access the file ?
What is the error you got...

Comment: I mean when i open the project root, there is not any public folder there

Comment: could you please post your htaccess file?

Comment: Istn't the public folder supposed to be the web root?

Comment: "my .htacess file inside the /public folder" -- so you finally found the public folder?? o_O

Comment: @nuqqsa, sorry for the confusion. I can't view/access the folder from the browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED**
You need to enable Apache's mod_rewrite. To do this

- Find the **httpd.conf** file (usually you will find it in a folder called conf, config or something along those lines)
- Inside the **httpd.conf** file uncomment the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` (remove the pound '#' sign from in front of the line)
- Also find the line ClearModuleList is uncommented then find and make sure that the line AddModule mod_rewrite.c is not commented out.

For Further information, go to the source
http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Apache-Tutorial-Enable-Mod_rewrite-Windows_t11623.html

**PREVIOUS**
If you set up your virtual host the default way, i.e.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/Users/user/www/yourdomain.dev/public"
   ServerName .local

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "C:/Users/user/www/yourdomain.dev/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

You may access the public dir, by:

```
http://yourdomain.dev/
```

and files in public dir by:

```
http://yourdomain.dev/filename.ext
```

It is all about `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: however, if I remove .htaccess file it is showing up. So there is something about .htaccess file

Comment: @Starx Is mod_rewrite enabled? To enable it: `a2enmod rewrite` and restart Apache.

Comment: Take a look at Apache's error.log, it may give you more info on what's going on. Also: 1) Is Apache mod_rewrite installed? 2) Note that if you set up the application in a subdomain, e.g. `http://localhost/myapp` rather than in the root of the domain, you'll need to add `RewriteBase /myapp/` in your .htaccess file.

Comment: @nuqqsa, apache error log is giving this error, E:/wamp/www/ZendPractice/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: @takesin, where to enable `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: @Starx This is command for Ubuntu, Google for other operating systems. Look for mod_rewrite in output of the `phpinfo()` function.

Comment: No there isn't any mod_rewrite in the display of phpinfo() and is apache's php.ini. Can you actually see the .htaccess output I provided and see what is hiding the folder

Comment: @Starx What's your OS? You just have to enable mod_rewrite, and it will be fine.

Comment: @takeshin: Thanks a lot, I found a way to enable mod_rewrite. I will update your answer and provide the link